# Kerning in italic contractions when using EB Garamond

Tags: spacing, typography, kerning, ebgaramond

I'm using EB Garamond to typeset some text and find that the kerning in italic contractions can be a bit generous for my taste. Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\noindent I’m It's I've\\
{\itshape I’m It's I've}\\
didn't don't hadn't wouldn't\\
{\itshape didn't don't hadn't wouldn't}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

IMHO, the spacing between the n's and the t's is too large when using italics. Is there an easy way to adjust it?

Comment: Check if it happens with xelatex/lualatex and the otf version of the font too and the write the author of the font and ask for adjustment.

Comment: With both xelatex and lualatex, I get warnings such as `Font shape 'T1/EBGaramond(0)/m/it' undefined` and therefore the italic words show up in roman font. Not sure how to try the otf version, so I'll try to contact the author...